# Handling inconsistent output in Bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

If the Bash output is not always consistent and some of the fields are 'not available' as below, what would be the best way to get all the results in a given column?

```
Slot        Serial          Device           State         Link                UUID     

Slot01      SERIAL_1        /dev/sda        Status_1                    uuid-uuid-uuid-uuid 

Slot02                                      Status_2

Slot03                                      Status_1    /mountpoint3/

Slot04      SERIAL_4        /dev/sdd        Status_4    /mountpoint4/   uuid-uuid-uuid-uuid 

Slot05                                      Status_4    /mountpoint5/
```

Answer (score 1):

`cut -c` lets you specify column counts:

```
$ cut -c '1-12' < input.txt
Slot01
Slot02

$ cut -c '13-28' < input.txt
SERIAL_1
```

Don't forget trim the string and check if they're empty to get rid of trailing spaces and check for empty values.